# Calling functions in a DLL from Qt (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I Want to use MediaInfo.dll downloaded from here [DLL   v0.7.94][1]

[1]: https://mediaarea.net/bg/MediaInfo/Download/Windows. My question is how to call some function in this .dll using Qt framework

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    if (QLibrary::isLibrary("MediaInfo.dll")) { // C:/MediaInfo.dll
      QLibrary lib("MediaInfo.dll");
      lib.load();
      if (!lib.isLoaded()) {
        qDebug() << lib.errorString();
      }

      if (lib.isLoaded()) {
        qDebug() << "success";
      }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are you linking to the DLL or are you using LoadLibrary(windows) / dload (*nix).

Comment: @cup I edit my post. I dont know how i can access to some function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good example in [`QLibrary`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html#details) documentation. Basically you have to know the function name (the *symbol*) and it's prototype.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    if (QLibrary::isLibrary("MediaInfo.dll")) { // C:/MediaInfo.dll
      QLibrary lib("MediaInfo.dll");
      lib.load();
      if (!lib.isLoaded()) {
        qDebug() << lib.errorString();
      }

      if (lib.isLoaded()) {
        qDebug() << "success";

        // Resolves symbol to
        // void the_function_name()
        typedef void (*FunctionPrototype)();
        auto function1 = (FunctionPrototype)lib.resolve("the_function_name");

        // Resolves symbol to
        // int another_function_name(int, const char*)
        typedef int (*AnotherPrototypeExample)(int, const char*);
        auto function2 = (AnotherPrototypeExample)lib.resolve("another_function_name");

        // if null means the symbol was not loaded
        if (function1) function1();
        if (function2) int result = function2(0, "hello world!");
      }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a function prototype and get a pointer to a function in DLL.

```
QLibrary myLib("mylib");
typedef void (*MyPrototype)();
MyPrototype myFunction = (MyPrototype) myLib.resolve("mysymbol");
if (myFunction)
    myFunction();
```

See more on [QLibrary](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html#details).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use QLibrary when there is a C/C++ binding?

[Include file with functions prototypes](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/master/Source/MediaInfoDLL/MediaInfoDLL.h).
[Example with dynamic call of the DLL](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/master/Source/Example/HowToUse_Dll.cpp).

A bit hidden, but all is included in the the DLL zip package in the link you provided in your question.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo